# Mono Linux. Логирование Http(s) сообщений

Tags: linux, mono

Я использую Mono Rapsberry pi(Linux). Никак не могу залогировать Http(s) Web service запросы. В Windows все работает как надо, а в Linux просто игнорирует мой конфиг.

Конфиг (не работает):

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>      
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="myListener"
           type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="TextOutput.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

В чем может быть проблема?